# Dynamically create a component inside an ngIf

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 6 and I've tried following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811809/add-component-dynamically-inside-an-ngif) but I can't get it to work

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {
  defaultToTrue = true;
  @ViewChildren('parent', { read: ViewContainerRef }) parent: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

  constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    const resolve = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
    this.parent.changes.subscribe(changes => {
      this.parent.createComponent(resolve); //Error
    });
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="defaultToTrue">
  <div #parent></div>
</div>
```

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvxn6w)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cito7r?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @yurzui Thanks but the problem with this is I get an "Expression changed after it was checked error". However I don't see this on stackblitz.

Comment: Okay, I deleted my answer as it was wrong. You have to find out yourself whether your app ever enters AfterViewInit. But keep in mind what I said below: Inside your subscription, `parent` is still a list of type `QueryList<ViewContainerRef>`. This list hasn't the same methods as a plain ViewContainerRef. You can't use `this.parent.createComponent(resolve);` here. This is still true although my suggestion to a solution didn't work out.

Comment: Does @yurzui's suggestion work (notwithstanding the exception)?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes it does

Comment: So you only need to get rid of the exception? One of these two techniques may help: (1) to call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` after `createComponent`; (2) to call `createComponent` asynchronously with `setTimeout(() => { this.parent.createComponent(resolve); })`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Thank you! I might have to go with option 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get rid of the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`, you can use one of the techniques suggested in [this Angular In Depth blog post](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4):

**Force change detection with `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`**:

```
constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit(){
  const resolve = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
  this.parent.changes.subscribe(changes => {
    this.parent.createComponent(resolve);
    this.cd.detectChanges();  // Trigger change detection
  });
}
```

**Create the component asynchronously with `setTimeout`**:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  const resolve = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
  this.parent.changes.subscribe(changes => {
    setTimeout(() => { this.parent.createComponent(resolve); });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My case is the `#container` is inside 2 `*ngFor`'s and all that inside `*ngIf`

the only way i could even get an instance of `ViewContainerRef` or `QueryList<ViewContainerRef>` is in `ngAfterViewChecked`, and only inside a condition, and even that running with a `setTimeout`

EDIT: must add a flag to stop or this is running endlessly

```
if (this.fieldsContainer && this.componentsGenerated == false) {
  this.componentsGenerated = true
  setTimeout(this.generateComponents.bind(this))
}
```

EDIT2:
in the end needed much more code to handle all that AND use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` with `cd:ChangeDetectorRef`

```
ngAfterViewChecked(): void {

  if (this.fieldsContainersQuery && this.componentsGenerated == false) {
    this.componentsGenerated = true

    this.fieldsContainersQuery.changes.subscribe(changes=>{
      this.fieldsContainersQuery.forEach(fieldContainerItem => this.generateComponents(fieldContainerItem))
      this.cd.detectChanges()
   })
 }
```

more details

[blog](https://bresleveloper.blogspot.com/2019/07/the-great-angular-dynamic-components.html)
[github](https://github.com/bresleveloper/ngSuperDynamicsComponent)