# ViewContainerRef is undefined when called in ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular, angular6, viewchild

I want to dynamically create a child component when the parent component is initialised, but when I tried to create it in ngAgterViewInit(), it throws the error that the ViewContainerRef is undefined.

component.ts

```
  @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
    this.container.createComponent(factory); //container is undefined here

  }
```

component.html

```
...
<div class="row" #container ></div>
...
```

Comment: Is the `div` inside an `ngIf` conditional block?

Comment: The code itself is working correctly, just tried.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, yes, it's inside an ngIf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50789503/dynamically-create-a-component-inside-an-ngif/56860518#56860518

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `div` is inside an `ngIf` conditional block, it may not be available in `ngAfterViewInit`. You can protect the code against that possibility by monitoring the presence of the element with `ViewChildren` and the `QueryList.changes` event:

```
@ViewChildren('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) containers: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (this.containers.length > 0) {
    // The container already exists
    this.addComponent();
  };

  this.containers.changes.subscribe(() => {
    // The container has been added to the DOM
    this.addComponent();
  });
}

private addComponent() {
  const container = this.containers.first;
  const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
  container.createComponent(factory);
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n61rj6) for a demo.